# Android app not connecting to localhost - Connection to localhost refused

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, xampp

I am trying to send data from an Android app to a PHP script hosted on a localhost server. The PHP file is located in the htdocs of my XAMPP folder, where I've always placed it. Here is my method for sending data:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNumber", user.phoneNumber));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        //HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/register.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I submit data, I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused
```

I've tried changing the ip address to localhost, but that changes nothing.

Here is my PHP script

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "is_clients");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$phoneNumber = $_POST["phoneNumber"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password, phoneNumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sisss", $name, $age, $username, $password, $phoneNumber);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

The purpose of which is to send data to a MySQL database with no password.

How can I access the PHP script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you try to access 127.0.0.1 from a phone, it will try to access itself. enter your computer's ip.

Comment: For sanity, double check that you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in the manifest file.

Comment: @skandigraun thank you for making the distinction. Everything is now working just fine. Thanks!